# Adding Font Features to only certain Font Shapes

Tags: fonts, fontspec

How do I add some font features (such as ligatures) to only certain font shapes?

The ideas is to disable ligatures for RB, RBI shapes, etc. since they give me a warning anyway.

I briefed over the documentation, but to no avail.

MWE (not compilabile without font files)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\defaultfontfeatures[LinLibertine_]{
    Extension      = {.otf},
    UprightFont    = {*R},
    BoldFont       = {*RB},
    ItalicFont     = {*RI},
    BoldItalicFont = {*RBI},
    Ligatures      = {Common, Rare, Historic, TeX}, 
    Numbers        = {OldStyle},
}

\setmainfont{LinLibertine_}

\begin{document}
\textbf{ff fi fl...}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the options `BoldFeatures={ Ligatures={...}}`, and so on.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\defaultfontfeatures[LinLibertine]{
    Extension      = {.otf},
    UprightFont    = {*_R},
    UprightFeatures = { Ligatures  = {Common, Rare, Historic, TeX}},
    BoldFont       = {*_RB},
    BoldFeatures = { Ligatures = {Common, Historic, TeX}},
    ItalicFont     = {*_RI},
    ItalicFeatures = { Ligatures  = {Common, Rare, Historic, TeX}},
    BoldItalicFont = {*_RBI},
    BoldItalicFeatures = { Ligatures = {Common, Historic, TeX}}, 
    Numbers        = {OldStyle},
}

\setmainfont{LinLibertine}

\begin{document}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

You could also try turning `Ligatures=Rare` on by default and off for a particular face, with `BoldTialicFeatures={ Ligatures=NoRare }`.

Comment: It's that straight forward! Thanks.